# rid of date in edit line in excel js file

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, exceljs

I have excel table with timings created with excel js.

I need to show timings only without dates (h:mm). I can do it in a cell, it's OK, but not in edit line, how can I fix it?(

`time: new Date(moment.utc().hours(h).minutes(m).seconds(0))`

`{ key: 'time', width: 7, style: { numFmt: 'h:mm' } },`

[image: edit line]

[image: table cells]

there is no this info in docs or google. I tried to create date by several ways, but it couldn't resolve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
// Create a workbook object
var workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

// Add a worksheet
var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Sheet1');

// Get the cell A1
var cell = worksheet.getCell('A1');

// Set the number format to 'h:mm'
cell.numFmt = 'h:mm';

// Get the current time in milliseconds
var currentTime = Date.now();

// Create a date object with the current time
var time = new Date(currentTime);

// Get the time components in UTC
var hours = time.getUTCHours();
var minutes = time.getUTCMinutes();
var seconds = time.getUTCSeconds();

// Create a date object with the UTC time components
var utcTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, hours, minutes, seconds);

// Set the cell value to the time with a newline character at the beginning
cell.value = '\n' + utcTime;
```